# hide or filter divs depending on value of textbox using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a textbox with Id `server_name`. I want to use the value in this to hide divs with class `server_wrapper` containing it.

What I have so far below successfully hides divs with class `server_wrapper` when the string in `#server_name` is not in its ID.

What I need now is functionality so that when you delete letters from `#server_name` it shows the divs that were hidden.

```
    $('#server_name').keyup(function() {
        if ($(this).val() == "") {
            $('.server_wrapper').show();
        } else {
            $('.server_wrapper').filter('div:not([id*=' + $(this).val() + '])').hide();
        }
    });
```

Comment: post your html, i have to see this div that id starts with the value you supposetly type

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to check which key is pressed, and if it's backspace (or delete) then show the items:

```
$('#server_name').keyup(function(e) {
        if ($(this).val() == "" || e.keyCode === 8 || e.keyCode === 46) {
            $('.server_wrapper').show();
        } else {
            $('.server_wrapper').filter('div:not([id*=' + $(this).val() + '])').hide();
        }
    });
```

Comment: You code worked great. I made the slight change of separating the if statement.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#server_name').keyup(function(e) {
            $('.server_wrapper').show().filter('div:not([id*=' + $(this).val() + '])').hide();
    });
```